# Grails 2.5 : Resource not found (404) for GSP file

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp

I am upgrading my Grails application from version 1.x to 2.5 and facing this issue in version 2.5 which worked fine in version 1.x

In GSP file (connect.gsp) I am trying to open another gsp rename.gsp. This rename.gsp file is in the same location as that of connect.gsp. However, the file is not found and 404-Resource not found error is shown in the pop-up.

connect.gsp (javascript code)

```
showPopWin("${request.getContextPath()}/user/rename.gsp", 280, 160, returnFunction);
```

Location of gsp files:

```
grails-app
     - views
          -user
              -connect.gsp
              -rename.gsp
```

Is anything related to GSP file loading changed in Grails 2.x version ? Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like resources rendering is changed in Grails 2.x

I have added below workaround:

In places where I have to call a gsp page (not controller action) from another gsp, then submit it first to controller action and from there use render to go to respective gsp file.

That is, in connect.gsp

```
showPopWin("${request.getContextPath()}/user/renameUI", 280, 160, returnFunction);
```

In UserController add an action renameUI,

```
def renameUI= {
    render( view : 'rename', model:[params:params])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think grails is looking for an url mapping.

You should create an action in a controller, this action must render the gsp file.

Simple example :

```
CustomcontrolController {

    def renamedisplay()
    {
        render(view: '/user/rename')
    }
}
```

then by default grails will map the following url :

```
showPopWin("${request.getContextPath()}/customcontrol/renamedisplay", 280, 160, returnFunction);
```

Or you can specify a specific url not generated by grails by editing UrlMappings.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Grails provide the redirect future in order to call one action from another action.
But here when connect action is get call then redirect to rename action

```
   def userController () {
           def connect () {

              redirect(action: "rename")
              //  or redirect(controller: "user", action: "rename") 
           } 
          def rename() {

          } 
 }
```

if want call to `rename.gsp` from `connect.gsp` you can use `window.location.href`

```
window.location.href="${request.getContextPath()}/user/rename" 
or

window.location.href="${request.getContextPath()}/user/rename.gsp"
```